# Video playlist in my React app running in WebView on Android glitches every second

Tags: android, reactjs

I already set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest and in the WebView setup

```
   layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    settings.apply {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        domStorageEnabled = true
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
        loadWithOverviewMode = true
        useWideViewPort = true
        allowContentAccess = true
        cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
        allowFileAccess = true
        databaseEnabled = true
    }
    scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
    clearCache(true)
    webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
```

I expect the video playlist to play smoothly without interruption every second.